# Drivers for NVIDIA GeForce4 MX 440 with AGP8X (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-geforce

I have Windows 7 installed on my machine. I am trying to install driver for my graphics card but I can't because the driver [software](http://www.nvidia.com/object/winxp_2k_93.71_2.html) works only on Windows 2000, XP, Media Center Edition.
The setup fails to load on Windows 7 machine saying "The operating system is not Windows" and then stops the installer.
But some users have installed this card on Windows 7. Any ideas whow to get card to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The card is far too old to support the Vista kernel's graphics requirements. No driver has been made since it does not have the needed capabilities.

No Windows XP driver will work on the Vista kernel, either (and that means 7, too).

Some people have managed to get some use out of the card by using the Vista/7 version of Nvidia's 61.76 WHQL drivers. They must be installed manually.

Stability is, of course, not guaranteed and problems such as difficulty with entering and recovering from both sleep and hibernation can be expected on some machines.

Answer (score 4):

Hey I had the same problem for some time! I just installed [forceware 72.14](http://download.cnet.com/NVIDIA-ForceWare-72-14-Windows-XP-MCE-2004-2005/3000-2108_4-102627.html) and it works flawlessly for my Drivers for NVIDIA GeForce4 MX 440 (pci) on Windows 7.

Before running the setup i had to set to compatibility mode for Xp SP3

Comment: -1. Now Windows 7 isn't booting, Black Screen. BIG THANKS.

Comment: I can only say what worked for me. The card it self is old anyway hence the lack of support. I only told you what i did to get it working

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me so I installed `77.72_win2kxp_english_whql` and it works in windows 7 ,however it doesn't seem support aero effects in windows 7. You can still play 2004 games with it like world of warcraft.

Comment: I can't test this out, cause I have new PC. BTW thanks for your response =)